# Design a combination circuit which can detect prime numbers from 0 to 15?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

No idea how to attack this question, full question being:

> "Design a combination circuit which can detect prime numbers from 0 to 15.  There should be a single output line, which would be 1 if the input is a prime number, otherwise the output line would be 0"

How would I go about completing this question? It looks fairly involved.

Comment: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 and 13 are the primes between 0 and 15, can you make a circuit to output one when the input is one when it's a number in that list and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Hint: Write down all of the possible input combinations and the corresponding output for each.

Answer (score 7):

Procedure:

1. Identify all the prime numbers between 0 and 15 (2, 3, 5, 7, 11,
   13).
2. Determine how many bits you need for a maximum value of 15
   (four bits).
3. Construct a Karnaugh map of the appropriate size and mark all prime numbers as logical 1 and all non-primes as logical 0.
4. Reduce the Karnaugh map to find your logic function.

I'll leave you to do the grunt work yourself.

Comment: Doesn't even need a K-map. Just group them into bit-difference groups: 2-3, 5-7, 3-7-11, 5-13.

Comment: It's lucky if the input is just 4-bits, How about 64-bit input? Should I use KMap and identifying manually from 0 until 2⁶⁴-1